# MS Teams incoming connector and images

Tags: microsoft-teams

In MS Teams I have an incoming webhook that includes an image in a Card.

I am trying to determine if the image I used in then stored in Microsoft's Cloud ? For example if the image is removed from the location that I included in the Card does this now not show in the Card or does MS Teams store the image somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this specifically with a webhook, but I can't imagine it's different from any other cards - when you reference an image, you do so by providing an endpoint (https://...). While Teams *does* seem to do some kind of caching with it, but it's quite shortlived (I think more for CDN-style performance), and the image needs to remain in it's place for it to show properly over time inside Teams.

Comment: To add one more point, you could also [embed base64 image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57034497/576503) in your card.

Comment: oh, wasn't aware of that - definitely need to test it out - thanks Wajeed!

Comment: I have an image attached to a card via HTTP (rather than base64), the image URL expires 8 hours ago and is still appearing in MS Teams channel. Going to see the CDN cache over time. I like the idea of base64 - thanks for that suggestion